# Float left is not putting div on the left side of previous div (second one overlaps the first)

Tags: html, css, layout

I have problem with: float: left code. Last, the third box overlaps the second box. Which causes the text TEXT2 to overlap TEXT3. I want that the 3rd box is on the right of the 2nd box, right after it (please don't use float: right).

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6d7ebatr/2/).

CSS & HTML code together:
(I know that css should be in external file, but this is in design mode:)

```
   <div style="float: left;">
            <div style="position: relative;">
              <div style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; top:0; right 0;">
                <img src="images/featured-taxtips.png" width="200px" />
              </div>
              <div style="z-index: 4; position absolute; top:0; right 0;">
                <img src="images/featured-gradient.png" width="200px" />
              </div>
              <div style=
                "z-index: 6; position: absolute; top:0; right 0;">
                TEXT1</div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div style="float: left;">
            <div style="position: relative;">
              <div style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; top:0; right 0;">
                <img src="images/featured-lifestyle.png" width="200px" />
                </div>
              <div style="z-index: 4; position: absolute; top:0; right 0;">
                <img src="images/featured-gradient.png" width="200px" />
                </div>
              <div style="z-index: 6; position: absolute; top:10px; left 10px;">TEXT2</div>
            </div>
         </div>

        <div style="float: left;">
          <div style="position: relative;">
            <div style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; top:0; right 0;">
              <img src="images/featured-video.png" width="200px" />
            </div>
            <div style="z-index: 4; position: absolute; top:0; right 0;">
              <img src="images/featured-gradient.png" width="200px" />
            </div>
            <div style="z-index: 6; position: absolute; top:10px; left 10px;">TEXT3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/6d7ebatr/4/)

Remove position absolute on second div's first div.

```
 <div style="float: left;">
    <div style="position: relative;">
      <div style="z-index: 2;">
        <img src="images/featured-lifestyle.png" width="200px" />
        </div>
      <div style="z-index: 4; position: absolute; top:0; right 0;">
        <img src="images/featured-gradient.png" width="200px" />
        </div>
      <div style="z-index: 6; position: absolute; top:10px; left 10px;">TEXT2</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Reason1:
    You dont have height and width.

Reason2: 
   Since you dont have height and width, absolute positioning inside relative div causes overlapping.

Comment: It seems to work ok, but why it was wrong:). Any logic explanation?

Comment: You are forcing TEXT2 div and TEXT3 div to start from same starting position. `absolute position inside relative`

Comment: I dont understand it:). Why 3rd box is overlapping second one?

Answer (score 0):

add 'width' and 'height' value for

```
<div style="float: left;">
```

elements. like

```
<div style="float: left; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
```

Comment: Could you add demo for this?

Comment: looks good, as   user3801433 said this maybe connected with width values. Thanks.